# Breaking conformal symmetry to Poincare symmetry

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, conformal-field-theory, symmetry-breaking, poincare-symmetry

If I have a free massless scalar field $\phi$ in (3+1)D Minkowski spacetime, the vacuum state is not only Poincare-invariant, but actually also conformally invariant. Is there a way to break the conformal symmetry to Poincare symmetry "dynamically"?

I put quotation marks because it is sort of paradoxical. If I do this by time-dependent mass $m(t) = 0$ at $t<0$ and $m(t)=m_0>0$ at $t>0$ (with possible smoothening), then it does not work because it breaks time-translational symmetry --- note that massive scalar field is in its own right Poincare-invariant. At the same time, in the case of Rindler vacuum, it breaks conformal invariance by (also) breaking spatial translation symmetry. So I used the word "dynamically" for lack of better choice, but is there a way to do this "nicely"?

Since I cannot make this precise enough, I would welcome any attempts that come close to this, in case "dynamical" methods do not exist or if I need to clarify this more precisely.